# How to get the value of X and Y after changing the angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I drew this picture to interpret my question.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I have an object that will initially be at **X: 0** **Y: 0** with an angle of **0º**, being **70 wide and 100 high**. I need to obtain the new value of the **X** and **Y** axis after this same object is rotated to an angle of **45º**.

How can I get this value, since the correct value would be X: -25.1 and Y: 39.39

Comment: This is not yet clear. You should [edit] the pictures in your question to show us just where the point $x=0, y=0$ is in that picture, and just where it has moved to after the rotation. Also tell us what you need to know, since you already seem to know the new values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @CrSb0001 I used the Figma software and created a 70x100 object in X:0 Y:0 starting with an angle of 0º, and when changing the angle of this object to 45º I obtained the new values of X: -25.1 and Y: 39.39.
The objective is to know what new position the object will occupy after it is rotated, I need this for a programming project.

Comment: @EthanBolker I need to know how to obtain the values of X and Y after rotating an object that can be anywhere in X and Y, I used as an example this 45º rotation that returned .

Comment: Still unclear. The general formulas are here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix but you have not described enough so see how they apply in your picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you wanted to know about a rotated rectangle of size $(a,b)$, and its bounding box.

[image: fig1]

In the example above the rectangle is rotated by a counter-clockwise angle of $\theta$.

$$\begin{aligned}y & =a\sin\theta\\
x & =b\sin\theta\\
w & =a|\cos\theta|+b|\sin\theta|\\
h & =a|\sin\theta|+b|\cos\theta|
\end{aligned}$$

where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value.

If the angle is negative then use the same equations as above but the definitions of $(x,y)$ offsets is a bit different (see below).

[image: fig2]

---

Also note that a point $(a,b)$ rotated by a CCW angle $\theta$ has coordinates
$$ {\rm rot}\left(\pmatrix{a\\b},\theta\right)=\pmatrix{a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta\\a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta} $$